# 403 Error while getting images but not other resources

Tags: php, xampp, http-status-code-403

I have xampp installed on ubuntu (`/opt/lampp`) and I created a public_html folder (I think it is a symbolic link, I am new with linux) in `/home/mustafa/public_html` I put my php files and other resources in the `public_html` folder, the problem is when I want to get things like images I get a 403 Error (Access forbidden) but other files are ok like PHP, CSS, JS files. What is the problem? What should I do?

***UPDATE***

the output of `ls -l /home/mustafa/public_html/templates/assets/images/` in terminal:

```
total 8
-rwxrwx--- 1 mustafa mustafa 4638 Feb 17 22:06 hbg.png

ls -l /home/mustafa/public_html/templates/assets/style/

total 16
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mustafa mustafa 1571 Feb 23 13:06 style.css
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mustafa mustafa 1567 Feb 23 13:06 style.css~
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mustafa mustafa  689 Feb 23 18:07 style_I.css
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mustafa mustafa  691 Feb 23 17:58 style_I.css~
```

I moved images to other directories and found that I cannot access any images in public_html and children directories

Comment: Are your images in the same directory as the other files you can access or something else? e.g are you images in `/images/` while your css, js etc are in `/assets/`?

Comment: images are in the `~/public_html/assets/images/` css files are in `~/public_html/assets/style/` and... also I moved the images from images folder to `css` folder but it doesn't work and I get 403 error again. but I can successfully load css files js files php html etc files

Comment: Can you edit your answer and paste the output of `ls -l ~/public_html/assets/images/` or `ls -l ~/public_html/assets/images/styles` including at least one image and one css file?

Comment: Have you checked the image files permissions? Not the folder but the individual files.

Comment: Looks to me that the `other` group can't access `hbg.png`. It's showing `rwxrwx---` while your css files are `rw-rw-r--`. You should `chmod 664` your images so they match your css files, or `chown apache` all the files (assuming apache runs as apache) and see if that works.

Comment: Oh yes I changed the permissions of image files for others to read-only it was none! thanx guys

Comment: Sweet, added answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me that the other group can't access images based on your `ls -l` output.

It's showing `rwxrwx---` while your css files are `rw-rw-r--`.

You should `chmod 664` your images so they match your css files, or `chown apache` all the files (assuming apache runs as apache) and see if that works.

To check which process is running apache you can use `ps aux | grep httpd`

```
[user@host ~]$ ps aux | grep httpd
root      6407  0.0  0.3  11204  3288 ?        Ss   09:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6409  0.0  0.2  11340  2952 ?        S    09:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6410  0.0  0.2  11340  2948 ?        S    09:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6411  0.0  0.2  11340  2940 ?        S    09:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6412  0.0  0.2  11340  2948 ?        S    09:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6413  0.0  0.2  11340  2948 ?        S    09:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6414  0.0  0.2  11340  2948 ?        S    09:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6415  0.0  0.2  11340  2948 ?        S    09:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6416  0.0  0.2  11340  2948 ?        S    09:06   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
root      6426  0.0  0.0   5500   720 pts/1    S+   09:14   0:00 grep httpd
```

Comment: how to do this in windows

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the shared hosting plan - make sure the settings in plesk don't have limit concurrent IP connections enabled and set to a certain number. I had this turned on and set to 10 concurrent connection (was just testing this option) and I would get a certain amount of files back - the rest would be forbidden and as a result some scripts could not be executed and such.

The same is likely true for linux hosting.

So those brothas testing and playing around with shared hosting - go to  Web Server Settings --> Preventing DoS attacks by IIS dynamic IP restriction - and make sure everything disabled.

Luck

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. I created a folder in img i.e. assets > img > some_folder. After reading @sjdaws answer, I looked my folder restrictions and found them to be problematic. Changing them to

```
chmod 0755 some_folder
```

solved my problem.

---

FYI: In linux

---

> 4 is for Read

> 2 is for write

> 1 is for execute

So

7 (4+2+1) means Read, write and execute

6 (4+2)   means Read, write

5 (4+1)   means Read        and execute

4         means Read

3 (2+1)   means       write and

execute

2         means       write

1         means                 execute

SO My answer of 755 meaning is

1. First 7 is for my account i.e. I had full access (read write and execute)
2. Second 5 is for other account in my group. 5 means they had read and execute access. Necessary because Appache (www account) need to read and execute access  some_folder.
3. Third 5 is for everybody else account. They also had read and execute access on some_folder.